# Daily unique count, weekly unique count in the same Timelion chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5, timelion

I want to visualize the unique count for a field aggregated daily and weekly per day in the same sheet. But timelion aggregation affects the entire sheet instead of just a single chart.

The expression I am using to get the daily unique count is

```
.es(metric='cardinality:userId').bars().title('Unique users over time')
```

If I change the bucket range on the right to 1d, I get the correct chart. How do I create the weekly aggregation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a possibility to specify the interval used for timelion expressions by specifying `interval` as `1d` or respectively `1w` in the `es()` function. For details, please see [the docs here](https://github.com/elastic/timelion/blob/master/FUNCTIONS.md#es).

In your case this should work with the following expression:

```
.es(metric='cardinality:userId',interval=1w).bars().title('Unique users per week')
```

Be aware of the comment inside the docs, stating that this should not be used in favor of working with the interval picker. But probably this is a use case where it is okay to do it like this...